# Error in getting item data from a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm reading a `json` file, retrieved from `openweathermap`, to get the temperature and rain expected for a location.
Here is an example of the [json file](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22)

I have a loop to retrieve for every index and i can get any value except rain.

```
result_data = []
result_tmax = []
result_prec = []
for item in data['list']:
   time = item['dt_txt']
   temperature = item['main']['temp_max']
   prec = item['rain']['3h']
   result_data.append(time)
   result_tmax.append(temperature)
   result_prec.append(prec)
```

I´m getting

> KeyError: 'rain'

Without the rain it works fine:

```
    future_date     future_temp
0   2019-10-17 12:00:00     18.45
1   2019-10-17 15:00:00     19.48
2   2019-10-17 18:00:00     17.03
3   2019-10-17 21:00:00     16.44
4   2019-10-18 00:00:00     15.67
5   2019-10-18 03:00:00     14.77
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: There is no `rain` in the json you posted.

Comment: 'rain' does not exist in the file, I did a `ctrl-f` on the doc for rain - it does not exist

Comment: Thanks's, it seems that rain (for snow the same) doesn´t come in that API all the times, only when the forecast will have rain.

Answer (score 1):

There is doesn't any key "rain" found in link which is given by you 
[click here.](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22][1])
I think you are looking for "snow".

Please replace "rain" with "snow" and test again. It will work.

Comment: Thanks's, it seems that rain (for snow the same) doesn´t come in that API  all the times, only when the forecast will have rain.

Comment: You can try.
prec = item['rain']['3h']
`if item['snow']:
     prec = item['snow']['3h']`

Answer (score 0):

This is my API call, not the example i pass (sorry for mistake):

```
 'list': [{'dt': 1571335200,
 'main': {'temp': 16.04,
'temp_min': 16.04,
'temp_max': 16.84,
'pressure': 1016,
'sea_level': 1016,
'grnd_level': 997.149,
'humidity': 87,
'temp_kf': -0.81},
 'weather': [{'id': 500,
 'main': 'Rain',
 'description': 'light rain',
 'icon': '10n'}],
 'clouds': {'all': 96},
 'wind': {'speed': 2.122, 'deg': 308.301},
 'rain': {'3h': 0.563},
 'sys': {'pod': 'n'},
'dt_txt': '2019-10-17 18:00:00'},
{'dt': 1571346000,
'main': {'temp': 15.74,
'temp_min': 15.74,
'temp_max': 16.35,
'pressure': 1018,
'sea_level': 1018,
'grnd_level': 998.455,
'humidity': 83,
'temp_kf': -0.61},
'weather': [{'id': 804,
 'main': 'Clouds',
 'description': 'overcast clouds',
 'icon': '04n'}],
'clouds': {'all': 97},
'wind': {'speed': 2.292, 'deg': 325.325},
'sys': {'pod': 'n'},
'dt_txt': '2019-10-17 21:00:00'}
```

At 2019-10-17 18:00:00 will have rain, at 21:00:00, there is no Rain and the Item Rain disapeer.

Anyone got an idea to solve this and avoid the error?